# Работа с библиотекой ObservableScrollView

Tags: java, android

Хочу использовать в своем приложении библиотеку [`ObservableScrollView`](https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView)

Не могу разобраться, как менять текст, выводимый в `TextView`, находящийся внутри элемента `ObservableScrollView`. 
Если данному элементу задать `ID` и назначать текст через `setText()`, то вся верстка ломается.
Может кто уже работал с данной библиотекой и может подсказать, как правильно с ней работать? В документации так и не нашел ответа на свой вопрос.

Comment: Напишите код где ломается

Answer (score 1):

Получилось установить текст следующим образом:

```
mScrollView = (ObservableScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scroll);
mScrollView.getRootView().findViewById(R.id.detail_description);
tDescription = (TextView) mScrollView.findViewById(R.id.detail_description);
tDescription.setText(Description);
```

Еще необходимо выставить минимальную высоту для TextView в котором находится текст.